# How to avoid duplicates when joining tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables that show how Loans connect to Borrowers, and how Loans connect to Real Estate property collateral pledged by the Borrowers. Some of the Loans are connected to 2 Borrowers. I want to see how much money all Borrowers that connect to an RE Property owe, without double-counting for loans where both borrowers are obligors. For example, assume the following tables:

**1. Loans**

| Loan_ID | Total_Claim |
| --- | --- |
| Loan_1 | 50,000 |
| Loan_2 | 30,000 |
| Loan_3 | 40,000 |

**2. Borrowers_Loans**

| Borrower_ID | Loan_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Borrower_1 | Loan_1 |
| Borrower_1 | Loan_2 |
| Borrower_2 | Loan_2 |
| Borrower_2 | Loan_3 |

**3. RE_Properties**

| Property_ID | Loan_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Property_1 | Loan_1 |
| Property_2 | Loan_2 |
| Property_3 | Loan_3 |

Now, I would like to calculate how much in total Borrowers that are connected to an RE property owe, as below:

| Property_ID | Total_Owed_By_Borrowers |
| --- | --- |
| Property_1 | 50,000 |
| Property_2 | 120,000 |
| Property_3 | 70,000 |

However, running the below double-counts Loan_2 (and shows the sum of Property_2 as 150,000), as it is connected to both Borrowers:

```
SELECT RE.Property_ID, SUM(L.Total_Claim)
FROM RE_Properties RE
INNER JOIN Borrowers_Loans BL ON BL.Loan_ID = RE.Loan_ID
INNER JOIN Borrowers_Loans BLA ON BLA.Borrower_ID = BL.Borrower_ID
INNER JOIN Loans L ON L.Loan_ID = BLA.Loan_ID
GROUP BY RE.Property_ID
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9280d4/2)

```
CREATE TABLE RE_Properties (
  Property_ID nvarchar(255),
  Loan_ID nvarchar(255));
  
CREATE TABLE Borrowers_Loans (
  Borrower_ID nvarchar(255),
  Loan_ID nvarchar(255));
  
CREATE TABLE Loans (
  Loan_ID nvarchar(255),
  Total_Claim int);
  
INSERT INTO RE_Properties (Property_ID, Loan_ID) VALUES ('Property_1', 'Loan_1');
INSERT INTO RE_Properties (Property_ID, Loan_ID) VALUES ('Property_2', 'Loan_2');
INSERT INTO RE_Properties (Property_ID, Loan_ID) VALUES ('Property_3', 'Loan_3');

INSERT INTO Borrowers_Loans (Borrower_ID, Loan_ID) VALUES ('Borrower_1', 'Loan_1');
INSERT INTO Borrowers_Loans (Borrower_ID, Loan_ID) VALUES ('Borrower_1', 'Loan_2');
INSERT INTO Borrowers_Loans (Borrower_ID, Loan_ID) VALUES ('Borrower_2', 'Loan_2');
INSERT INTO Borrowers_Loans (Borrower_ID, Loan_ID) VALUES ('Borrower_2', 'Loan_3');

INSERT INTO Loans (Loan_ID, Total_Claim) VALUES ('Loan_1', 50000);
INSERT INTO Loans (Loan_ID, Total_Claim) VALUES ('Loan_2', 30000);
INSERT INTO Loans (Loan_ID, Total_Claim) VALUES ('Loan_3', 40000);
```

Comment: What are you joining Borrowers_Loans on twice? If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML (or a fiddle) its much easier for us to work with (cos none of us want to type it all in again).

Comment: How do you get that `Total_Owed_By_Borrowers` amount for `Property_2` and `Property_3` ? Isn't it should be just `30,000` and `40,000` ?

Comment: Hello, the reason I am joining Borrowers_Loans twice, is that RE_Properties are connected to specific Loans, but I want to include all Loans that are connected to the Borrowers (who connect to RE properties via specific loans). So for example, a Borrower can have 5 loans, only 1 of which is directly connected to RE properties (but I want to see the sum of all 5 loans' Total_Claim). Here is the Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9280d4/2

Comment: Why do you want to include all borrowers when your desired results doesn't show anything without a property?

Comment: I've posted a very simplified example - probably a mistake on my side. Here is a more expanded example which contains Loans not connected to RE Properties http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e40b5/1 . In this case, the Total_Claim in the last table attributed to Property_2 should be (Loan_1 + Loan_2 + Loan_3 + Loan_4 + Loan_5 = 200,000) instead of  (Loan_1 + 2*Loan_2 + Loan_3 + Loan_4 + Loan_5 = 230,000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but using your query as a starting point you can ensure each loan is only counted once by grouping by `Loan_ID` and taking `MAX` for the amount (or `FIRST` it doesn't matter since we know its the same value) as follows:

```
WITH Cte as (
    SELECT RE.Property_ID
        , L.Loan_ID, MAX(L.Total_Claim) Total_Claim
    FROM RE_Properties RE
    INNER JOIN Borrowers_Loans BL ON BL.Loan_ID = RE.Loan_ID
    INNER JOIN Borrowers_Loans BLA ON BLA.Borrower_ID = BL.Borrower_ID
    INNER JOIN Loans L ON L.Loan_ID = BLA.Loan_ID
    GROUP BY RE.Property_ID, L.Loan_ID
)
SELECT Property_ID, SUM(Total_Claim)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY Property_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the intended output.
I have to say, I thought this would be an easy problem with an easier solution that I just couldn't think of (I can't really grasp yours as it uses statements I'm not familiar with - I'm not a programmer and just trying SQL as a pet project to help me with my main work). I guess I have some reading to do!

Comment: A CTE (common table expression started with the `WITH` keyword) is essentially a sub-query, which you use in this case to create some intermediate results which are then further transformed to give the final results. Nothing too complex to it. Its quite common that you can't create you final output in a single level of query.

Answer (score 1):

Risk to each borrower is sum of all loans associated with them (assuming they adopt the whole loan if any associated borrower defaults)

```
select bl.Borrower_ID, sum(loans.total_claim) borrower_total_risk
from Borrowers_Loans as bl
inner join Loans on bl.loan_id = loans.loan_id
```

Risk to each property is the value of the loans to that property

```
select p.Property_ID, sum(loans.total_claim) property_loan_total
from RE_Properties as p
inner join Loans on p.Loan_ID = loans.Loan_ID
group by p.Property_ID
```

If I was to combine this I wouldn't just do a simple sum, e.g.:

```
SELECT
      RE.Property_ID
    , max(L.Total_Claim) AS Total_Claim
    , count(distinct bl.Borrower_ID) num_borrowers 
    , min(b_risk.borrower_total_risk) as min_borrower_total_risk
    , max(b_risk.borrower_total_risk) as max_borrower_total_risk
FROM RE_Properties RE
  INNER JOIN Loans L ON L.Loan_ID = RE.Loan_ID
  LEFT JOIN Borrowers_Loans BL ON BL.Loan_ID = RE.Loan_ID
  LEFT JOIN (
              select bl.Borrower_ID, sum(loans.total_claim) borrower_total_risk
              from Borrowers_Loans as bl
              left join Loans on bl.loan_id = loans.loan_id
              group by bl.Borrower_ID
              ) as b_risk on bl.Borrower_ID = b_risk.Borrower_ID
GROUP BY RE.Property_ID;
```

**Results**:

```
| Property_ID | Total_Claim | num_borrowers | min_borrower_total_risk | max_borrower_total_risk |
|-------------|-------------|---------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|
|  Property_1 |       50000 |             1 |                   80000 |                   80000 |
|  Property_2 |       30000 |             2 |                   70000 |                   80000 |
|  Property_3 |       40000 |             1 |                   70000 |                   70000 |
```

Note that the count of borrowers shows 2 when it needs to and that does NOT require multiple joins to the same table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9280d4/26/1

Comment: Unfortunately this does not lead to the desired output. The objective of the exercise is as follows: Assume Property_2 is being auctioned and sold because the Borrowers have defaulted on all their loans. The Bank will not ask to be paid back from the auction proceeds only on the claim secured by the Property (i.e. Loan_2 - 30,000), but on all the claims attributed to the 2 Borrowers that are connected to the Property (e.g. owners) (therefore Loan_1 + Loan_2 + Loan_3 = 120,000). On the other hand, the Bank will also not claim 150,000, since this would assume the shared Loan_2 is owed twice.

Comment: this paragraph would have been useful in the question as it explains "why" always useful when answering.

Comment: The surprising new "fact" is that 'the Borrowers have defaulted on ALL of their loans'.  Are we then to expect that the Bank will auction Property_1 also, again for another 120,000? Etc...

Comment: No, because Property_1 is not secured by both Borrowers, so the max. claim by the Bank would be 50,000. Also, maybe Properties 1 & 3 are not worth a lot (e.g. Property 2 is a multimillion villa while 1 & 3 are underground storage rooms in villages), so no benefit for the bank to pay the legal costs to auction them. But this is not the point of my SQL troubles.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no need to involve Borrowers. Join only Properties and Loans

```
RE_Properties           Loans   
Property_ID Loan_ID     Loan_ID Total_Claim
Property_1  Loan_1      Loan_1  50000
Property_2  Loan_2      Loan_2  30000
Property_3  Loan_3      Loan_3  40000
                        Loan_4  10000
                        Loan_5  70000
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not lead to the desired output. The objective of the exercise is as follows: Assume Property_2 is being auctioned and sold because the Borrowers have defaulted on all their loans. The Bank will not ask to be paid back from the auction proceeds only on the claim secured by the Property (i.e. Loan_2 - 30,000), but on all the claims attributed to the 2 Borrowers that are connected to the Property (e.g. owners) (therefore Loan_1 + Loan_2 + Loan_3 = 120,000). On the other hand, the Bank will also not claim 150,000, since this would assume the shared Loan_2 is owed twice.

Comment: this paragraph would have been useful in the question as it explains "why" always useful when answering.